# Error while connecting to mySql DB with tomcat server

Tags: java, jdb

Im working on a struts based web application with tomcat server, using jdbc to connect the DB, and using mySql and sql server DB, and added related jars as well, but having this exception how to resolve the issue.

```
com.mind.fw.lang.MindFWRuntimeException: Error while doing JNDI lookup
    at com.mind.fw.core.dao.util.DBUtil.getJndiDS(DBUtil.java:186)
    at com.mind.fw.core.dao.util.DBUtil.initializeDS(DBUtil.java:157)
    at com.mind.fw.core.dao.util.DBUtil.getDataSource(DBUtil.java:132)
    at com.mind.common.util.MySqlConnection.getMySqlConnection(MySqlConnection.java:21)
    at com.mind.dao.PVS.Pvsdao.getSearchpartnerdetailsWithStatus(Pvsdao.java:1901)
    at com.mind.actions.PVS.Partner_SearchAction.search(Partner_SearchAction.java:371)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.mind.common.CharsetEncoding.doFilter(CharsetEncoding.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [contingentDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [contingentDB].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.mind.fw.core.dao.util.DBUtil.getJndiDS(DBUtil.java:181)
    ... 38 more
14 May 2014 06:16:31,625 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] util.MySqlConnection:27 - getMySqlConnection(String) - Error in establishing connection to mySQL.
14 May 2014 06:16:31,625 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4] PVS.Pvsdao:2225 -  -------------------------------------------- jdbc:mysql://ServerIP:3306/DBNaame,UserNAme,password -------------------------------------------- 
14 May 2014 06:16:31,625 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4] PVS.Pvsdao:2228 - getSearchpartnerdetails(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String, String, DataSource)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mind.dao.PVS.Pvsdao.getSearchpartnerdetailsWithStatus(Pvsdao.java:1937)
    at com.mind.actions.PVS.Partner_SearchAction.search(Partner_SearchAction.java:371)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.mind.common.CharsetEncoding.doFilter(CharsetEncoding.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
14 May 2014 06:16:31,626 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] PVS.Pvsdao:2233 - getSearchpartnerdetails(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String, String, DataSource) - Error occured during searchingjava.lang.NullPointerException
14 May 2014 06:16:31,626 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4] PVS.Pvsdao:2240 -  -------------------------------------------- jdbc:mysql://ServerIP:3306/DBNaame,UserNAme,password --------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It looks like a null-pointer exception in getSearchpartnerdetailsWithStatus? What does that code look like?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Connection is null and when i try to call mySqlConn.createStatement() then it gives null pointer,

Comment: Did you have set correctly the jndi in Tomcat ?

Comment: @MaximeB. Could you please explain where to set, so that i may confirm it. im working on a running project.

Comment: @zzzz See the following documentation : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html, section "UserDatabase Resources".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

Actually this was the original problem:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [contingentDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [contingentDB].
```

and i noticed that

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/contingentDB" name="jdbc/contingentDB"/>
```

was missing in the local context file i-e

```
tomcatInstances/verification/conf/Catalina/localhost/ProjectName.xml
```

Hope this will help someone.